# Making div in variable-height td height:100% that works cross-browser

Tags: css, cross-browser

Before someone start screaming "Don't use tables for layout", I haven't been able to create a non-table layout that works in my situation.

Directly setting `height: 100%` doesn't work for obvious reasons (well maybe not so obvious, but I understand why it doesn't work):

```
<td>
    <div style='height:100%'></div>
</td>
```

---

Tried to use absolute positioning:

```
<td style='position:relative'>
    <div style='position:absolute; top:0px; bottom:0px;'></div>
</td>
```

Breaks in FF because it doesn't recognize positioning on td. Also mysteriously breaks in IE9.

Comment: Don't use inline styles.

Comment: They are here for the sake of demo. Don't wanna post a separate block of code for CSS just for those.

Comment: @AspiringAqib be helpful don't try to point out mistakes only :)

Comment: use http://jsfiddle.net/ , save fiddle and share in your question for better help.

Comment: @Usman I am just finding a way to implement this simple idea: "make div fill the height of a variable-height td". Is a fiddle necessary? What do you expect I put into that fiddle?

Answer (score 0):

In order for a percentage value to work for height, the parent's height must be determined!

This means that the `td` elements needs to have `height` defined:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td style='height:100px'>
           <div style='height:100%'>hi</div>
       </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Oops! Missed the variable-height part in the title. Edited